# Multi-level bin-packing problem?

Tags: algorithms

Let us consider we have B Bags and each Bag has some number of Items. The problem is to distribute Bags of Items uniformly across as minimum number of Bins as possible.

However, there are two constraints:

1. Each Bin should not have more than K bags (say K = 2)
2. Each Bag in the Bin should contain at least N items (say N = 1).

A simple example:

Let us say we are given the following five Bags and the number of items in the corresponding bags (say input to the algorithm):

`(4), (1), (1), (4), (6)`

One of the possible solutions:

2 Bins, their corresponding bags and the number of items in the bags:

`Bin-1 with 2 bags: [ (4) (1) (3)]`

`Bin-2 with 2 bags: [ (4) (1) (3)]`

First of all, could someone please let me know if there is any classic name for this problem. I am not sure what to call this problem.

It would be great if someone could help me to solve this.

Note 1: The items in the bags are not identical and therefore we cannot combine different items in the same bag.

Note 2: We can split the given bags of items into as many bags as possible.

Note 3: The total number of items in the input bags == the total number of items in the Bins (finally).

Note 4: This is off-line, i.e., all the bags/items are given upfront.

Note 5: We need to use more than one Bin as there is a constraint on the number of items in the Bin. Please assume that there are actually a maximum of 4 Bins and we need to uniformly distribute the bags of items across the Bins. Please assume that minimum no of Bins 2 and maximum no of Bins 4.

Comment: I see we can repack the bags... (a) it seems that we don't have to use all the bags given - is this correct? (b) is there an upper limit on the number of items per bag?

Comment: @Joffan, sorry for the confusion. I have updated the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a "harder" version of the [Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) problem (By setting $K=B-1$, we can reduce Partition to this. Thus this problem is NP-Hard).